# Did the WHO deliberately skip the letters Xi and Nu when naming the latest COVID-19 variant Omicron?

Tags: covid-19, world-health-organization

[A tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/MartinKulldorff/status/1464299665432608771) claims WHO skipped a letter of the Greek alphabet when designating new COVID-19 variants to avoid using "xi".

> News of new Nu variant, but WHO is jumping the alphabet to call it Omicron, so they can avoid Xi.

Is there any information why it was skipped?

Can it be verified that the letter "Xi" was skipped for political reasons, to avoid the connection to the Chinese president Xi Jinping?

Comment: They skipped two - I am unclear whether *nu variant* was deemed too close to *mu variant* or to *new variant*

Comment: Last I heard there was delta, 4th position in [the Greek alphabet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL1cj.jpg). There are now 13 variants?

Comment: @fredsbend It's the fifth to be a variant of concern but not the fifth to be assigned a Greek letter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variants_of_SARS-CoV-2

Comment: @fredsbend [There are several COVID-19 variants you haven’t heard of](https://www.newsnationnow.com/health/coronavirus/there-are-several-covid-19-variants-you-havent-heard-of/). In fact, Nu and Xi are the first skipped letters.

Comment: Yeah, seems there's a good deal more than 15 (thousands according to newsnationnow above). Apparently it's a complicated and non-universal nomenclature.

Comment: @iBug that link is blocked to EU. "_This site is currently unavailable to visitors from the European Economic Area while we work to ensure your data is protected in accordance with applicable EU laws_". Luckily other links like the wikipedia one work

Comment: @bradbury9 [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://www.newsnationnow.com/health/coronavirus/there-are-several-covid-19-variants-you-havent-heard-of/) sometimes comes in handy.

Comment: To follow up on what @iBug and richardb said, there's a nice diagram showing the lineage of quite a few variants here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Tree_diagram_of_Pango_lineages_of_SARS-CoV-2.svg (from the wikipedia page richardb linked)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Yes, according to a reporter for the *Telegraph*:

> A WHO source confirmed the letters Nu and Xi of the Greek alphabet had been deliberately avoided. Nu had been skipped to avoid confusion with the word "new" and Xi had been skipped to "avoid stigmatising a region", they said.
>
> [Paul Nuki](https://twitter.com/PaulNuki/status/1464310918389587974)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131852/discussion-on-answer-by-avery-did-the-who-name-the-latest-covid-19-variant-omicr).

Answer (score 72):

The New York Times [names a WHO spokesman the paper quotes:](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/11/27/world/africa/omicron-covid-greek-alphabet.html)

> “‘Nu’ is too easily confounded with ‘new,’” Tarik Jasarevic, a W.H.O. spokesman, said on Saturday. “And ‘Xi’ was not used because it is a common last name.”
>
> He added that the agency’s best practices for naming diseases suggest avoiding “causing offense to any cultural, social, national, regional, professional or ethnic groups.”

My guess is that they would equally have skipped "Putin" or "Obama" if such letters existed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131868/discussion-on-answer-by-peter-reinstate-monica-did-the-who-name-the-latest-cov).

Comment: The WHO Best Practices for the Naming of New Human Infectious Diseases specifically states not to use people's names (although it gives plenty of counter examples...), so the same logic was probably applied here.  https://apps.who.int/iris/bitstream/handle/10665/163636/WHO_HSE_FOS_15.1_eng.pdf

Answer (score 23):

**Yes** (to avoid confusion and offence), as confirmed in [a statement by the WHO to The Associated Press](https://apnews.com/article/coronavirus-pandemic-science-health-media-social-media-12fdc1fc3b922466be577d4dd0acc6de):

> In a statement provided to the AP, the WHO said it skipped nu for
> clarity and xi to avoid causing offense generally.
>
> “‘Nu’ is too easily confounded with ‘new,’ and ‘Xi’ was not used
> because it is a common last name,” the WHO said, adding that the
> agency’s “best practices for naming disease suggest avoiding ‘causing
> offence to any cultural, social, national, regional, professional or
> ethnic groups.’”

Comment: How is this substantially different from the answer given by Peter - Reinstate Monica?

Comment: @computercarguy : it has a reference to a WHO press release, not a second-hand NY Times citation.

Comment: @computercarguy the source in the answer isn't paywalled -> better answer IMO